# What is the Message in WebView.requestFocusNodeHref (Message hrefMsg)?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the url of the image touched by a user in a `WebView`.
I use [`getHitTestResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getHitTestResult%28%29) but I need to handle cases where `getHitTestResult()` return `UNKNOWN_TYPE`.

The documentation suggests [`requestFocusNodeHref (Message hrefMsg)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#requestFocusNodeHref%28android.os.Message%29) but I don't understand what the [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) should be.

Thank you for any idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question here.
So this is how it works. The message in question must be sent to a `Handler` that will handle the request.

```
/*
 * Used to get the result of requestFocusNodeHref(msg)
 */
class MyHandler extends Handler{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        String src = msg.getData().getString("src");
        launchImageSaveAs(src);
        }
    }
```

Then, somewhere in your code, for example in `OnLongClickListener` you create a new message and set the handler as a target and finally call `requestFocusNodeHref`

```
if(result.getType() == HitTestResult.UNKNOWN_TYPE){
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setTarget(new MyHandler());
    webview.requestFocusNodeHref(msg);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in some cases the URL/src is not enough to load the new window correctly. The original and the new window may need to exchange messages, the same browser tabs can communicate with each other. In that case it seems you have to use the recommended approach of `transport.setWebView(newWebView); resultMessage.sendToTarget();` to directly load the new webview in the same activity as the original webview.